# A set with Borel preimage

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, fix a continuous surjection $f\colon X\to Y$.

Suppose $B\subseteq Y$ has the property that $f^{-1}[B]$ is Borel. Is $B$ necessarily Borel?

Note that if $X$ is metrisable, then this is true by Suslin's theorem, as then $f^{-1}[B]$ is analytic, and its complement is analytic as well, which easily implies that the same is true about $B$.

Since continuous maps between compact Hausdorff spaces are closed, it is true if the preimage is $F_\sigma$, and this implies the same for $G_\delta$ by complementation. So in a counterexample, we would need $f^{-1}[B]$ to be at best $F_{\sigma\delta}$ (or $G_{\delta\sigma}$).

I think it should be false in general, but I see no obvious counterexample.

Comment: I thought that any analytic set is the continuous image of a Borel set...

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for reading Suslin's theorem? Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Theorem 14.11 in Kechris' Classical descriptive set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Outside of Polish spaces, I guess it really depends how you define an analytic set (and probably where your Borel set is). How would it help?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore, actually.

Comment: Well, Hanul Jeon's deleted answer shows (more or less) that every subset of a compact Hausdorff space is the continuous image of an open (and hence Borel) set in a compact Hausdorff space (via a continuous surjection). But it doesn't seem to say much.

Comment: The answer is yes. See Steprans' post here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67858/images-of-borel-subsets-of-non-metric-compact-spaces

Comment: @hot_queen: Great! (Actually, it's kind of a bother, as I had to alter the thesis I had just finished writing, but it also makes it slightly more elegant.) You should post this as an answer.